# React Native Login Using WebAuth redirection to browser from app

Tags: authentication, auth0, webauthn

when login using Auth0 Webauth in React-Native it opens the browser for login.
I want to create a smooth login so that the user should not able to experienced whether I logged in using App or Browser jut like a webview anyone any idea?

Comment: Hi @syed did you get any solution regarding this, I have also the same situation to implement this in react native, will help if you could provide some info?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear are you asking if Auth0 supports doing this without a browser? Given that it's likely using OAuth2 or OpenID Connect then the short answer is no.

Further to that WebAuthn is a browser-based Javascript API so by definition would require a browser with these features to be available.

That said, there's probably nothing preventing you from implementing a native WebAuthn-like experience using CTAP2 (the protocol that sits underneath WebAuthn) directly or a platform-specific wrapper around the same.